# How can we delete the table row by specific word along with its digits from all .html files using perl?

Tags: perl

---

In the following code i had tried to delete the table from the .html files if it contains miminum digits along with specific character.Here every .html files will have some table row contents.Here the contents are named as like(rev1,rev2,rev3,rev4).

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $output_dir = "/projects/Griffin"; 

my @files_filter = sort
   File::Find::Rule->file()->name('*.html')->in($output_dir);
#print @files_filter;
my $max_file = pop @files_filter;
#print $max_file;
unlink $_ for @files_filter;

open my $fh, '<', $max_file or die $!;
#######refrence from #linux command #######
#perl -e 'print q(<table><tr class="normal">). (sort {$b cmp $a} grep {/rev/i} split /(?:<\/?tr[^>]*>\s*)+/i, join "", <>)[0] .q(</tr></table>)' database.html > database_reedit.html
my $cleaned = '<table><tr class="normal">'.
 (
      sort {
          my ($n) = $b =~ /rev(\d+)\.html/;
         my ($m) = $a =~ /rev(\d+)\.html/;
         $n <=> $m
#$b <=> $a
      }

          grep {/rev(\d+)/i}
             split /(?:<\/?tr[^>]*>\s*)+/i,   
                join "", <$fh>
     )[0] .
    '</tr></table>';
#print $cleaned;
close $fh;

open my $fh2, '>', $max_file or die $!;
print $fh2 $cleaned;
close $fh2;
```

From my above code i got the following error i am unable to fix the above error why it ocurs?

**Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at sample_rev.pl line 28,**

WHat i trying to convey you is from the code :

```
Here print @filter_files will have the following print statements:

/projects/griffin/chiptop/chiptop.html
/projects/griffin/svn/svn.hmtl
/project/griffin/chiptop/rev8/rev8.html
```

So now inside the chiptop.html i will have the following table row lines.

```
<tr class="normal">
                <td><a href="rev7/rev7.html">rev1</a></td>
                <td> 88.89% </td>
                <td> 88.89%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="normal">
                <td><a href="rev2/rev2.html">rev2</a></td>
                <td> 98.41% </td>
                <td> 98.41%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="normal">
                <td><a href="rev8/rev8.html">rev3</a></td>
                <td> 98.41% </td>
                <td> 100.00%</td>
            </tr>
```

So i tried to remove the table row which is not having maximum digit along with the word rev.So i had tried the above code to remove minimum digits from the html files .But it fails in my case .How can i do it?

IF the above file run properly means the only following contents should appear from the chiptop.html and other table row contents to be removed because here rev8 is the maximum one compared to other rev.

```
<tr class="normal">
                    <td><a href="rev8/rev8.html">rev3</a></td>
                    <td> 98.41% </td>
                    <td> 100.00%</td>
                </tr>
```

NEW UPDATED CODE:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -I /projects/lib
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $tree=HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new();
my $output_dir="/projects/Xenon_R3";
my @files=File::Find::Rule->file()
                ->name('*.html')                
                #->not( File::Find::Rule->name(qr/\d/) )
                ->in($output_dir);


# my $max_file=join "\n",@files;
    #print $max_file;
for $max_file (@files)
{
$tree->parse_file($max_file);

my @nodes=sort {$b->attr("href") cmp $a->attr("href")} $tree->findnodes("//tr/td/a[contains(\@href,'/rev')]");
print @nodes;
if($#nodes!=-1)
    {
    my $cleaned="<table>".$nodes[0]->parent->parent->as_HTML."</table>";
#last;
print $cleaned;



open my $fh2, '>', $max_file or die $!;
print $fh2 $cleaned;
close $fh2;
}
}
```

Comment: You'd probably find it a lot easier and more reliable to use a HTML parser rather than hacking around with the content using regex etc...

Comment: With HTML PARSER i feel it is impossible to do. Could please show me examples @ChrisTurner

Comment: Typing "HTML parsing perl" into the search box got me dozens of examples that you could look at

Comment: In regards to the warning you're getting, it's due to your code to extract the table rows returning an undefined cos it's not working properly.

Comment: am not clear what you trying to convey me is your are talking about  my $cleaned is not defined .@ChrisTurner

Comment: Not quite - I'm talking about what is being assigned to `$cleaned`. You're concatenating 3 things, two of which are string literals, the middle one is a complicated expression. The warning is telling you that one of those 3 things is undefined, which means the complicated expression isn't working

Comment: But without taking that expression how can i fix the expected output. Because that line is necessary one. @ChrisTurner

Comment: You have `my $cleaned = … . ( sort {…} grep {…} split … join … <$fh> )[0] . …;`. From my experience with such code it is better to step back and use some intermediate variables for the subresults and split the code into multiple statements. You can then perhaps better localize _what_ exactly is undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're getting is from concatenating an undefined value. You're getting an undefined value because your attempt to grab out all the relevant chunks of HTML from the file isn't working.

Trying to parse HTML with regular expressions isn't very reliable. It's far better and easier to use one of the many existing modules for parsing HTML as they should be able to cope with whatever HTML you happen to end up with.

Here is an example of how to do this.

It uses an XPath query to get the `a` tags we're after and sorts them in descending order by the `href` attribute. If there were any found, it takes the first one and wraps up the grandparent inside a `table` tag.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
my $tree=new HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

$tree->parse_file($max_file);

my @nodes=sort {$b->attr("href") cmp $a->attr("href")} $tree->findnodes("//tr/td/a[contains(\@href,'/rev')]");
if($#nodes!=-1)
    {
    my $cleaned="<table>".$nodes[0]->parent->parent->as_HTML."</table>";
    }
```

Comment: But your script will just print that maximum name and i want to remove other minimum named strings (like rev1,rev2 and rev3) and using argv[0] we should give the exact .html file location .I need to read the entire folder and take the all .html files.I think this method wont support for taking all .html files and removing the minimum digit character strings(i.e rev1,rev2 and rev3 expect rev4).beacuse here rev4 is maximum one. @Chris Turner

Comment: OK - I've simplified the example so that it focuses on the important part, namely the parsing of the HTML and extracting out the part you want. How you specify `$max_file` or what you do with `$cleaned` afterwards is up to you.

Comment: updated my new code .Here the code fails to run for multiple .html files under my folders and sub folders.If i gave the .html file location manually then it runs fine.If i try to use it for multiple .html files under my folders and sub folders that your code fails,This is what i about to convey you.My query is i want to do same action for multple .html files  @Chris Turner

Comment: Obviously what you've done won't work - you're combining all the filenames into `$max_file` which won't be a valid file name. You need to pass each member of `@files` through the parsing code 1 at a time with a for loop.

Comment: i had tried woth for loop too it fails will update in my code.You can view it @Chris Turner

Comment: How does it fail? Aside from that `print @nodes;` being outside the `if` statement, it looks like it should process all the files and update them.

Comment: But the nothing is processing inside for loop. It looks Empty @Chris Turner

Comment: That means the files you're trying to process don't have any of the HTML you're looking for inside of them. I tested my example code with the example HTML you have in the question and it pulled out the right chunk.

Comment: yes am looking inside the .html files.Inside those html files trying to sort the contents (i.e rev1,rev2 and rev3,rev4).Here rev4 is the maximum one so i try to remove the other terms like rev1,rev2 and rev3 from my .html file @Chris Turner